# Android Java Dice roll app not changing dinamycaly

Tags: java, android

This is my MainActivity. I want when I hit "roll" button dices to "roll" - change until my cycle finish and I want to see that change. But when I run the code and hit the button I see only the end result. Tried increasing the delay of "TimeUnit", but it only slows down my app, I don't see dices "rolling". Where am I wrong and is my code in the wright direction, or am I missing something important? I am still learning Android coding :)

```
    package com.example.rado.diceroller;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myButtonListenerMethod();
    }

    public void myButtonListenerMethod() {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rollButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    try {

                        Random rand = new Random();
                        int rollResult = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
                        TextView diceResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rollResult);
                        diceResult.setText(Integer.toString(rollResult));
                        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.diceImage);
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);

                        switch (rollResult) {
                            case 1:
                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice1);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice2);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice3);
                               break;
                            case 4:
                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice4);
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice5);
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice6);
                                break;
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: You mean you want to see the rolling animation?

Comment: Exactly, or at least a few pictures changing with the delay that I have given before I hit "roll" again.

Comment: You should increase the sleep time, 10 milliseconds is so fast that you can't notice the change. About 120 milliseconds may give you noticeable difference, again, it depends on the capability of the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that Android renders view changes after execution finish. So you can wait as many time as you want with TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep, the only result you will get will be that Android freezes himself for a bit, then restart the for loop. But he starts to render only when the execution is finished and he can say that he isn't wasting time and cpu to render something that the user will never see.

So you can't accomplish your goal in this way. You could try something like this:

```
package com.firegloves.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int rolledTimes = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myButtonListenerMethod();


    }

    public void myButtonListenerMethod() {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rollButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setTimeout();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTimeout() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (rolledTimes < 6) {
                    // roll your dice
                    rollDice();
                    // set timeout again
                    setTimeout();
                } else {
                    rolledTimes = 0;
                }
            }
        }, 100);
    }


    private void rollDice() {

        rolledTimes++;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int rollResult = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        TextView diceResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rollResult);
        diceResult.setText(Integer.toString(rollResult));
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.diceImage);

        switch (rollResult) {
            case 1:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice1);
                break;
            case 2:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice2);
                break;
            case 3:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice3);
                break;
            case 4:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice4);
                break;
            case 5:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice5);
                break;
            case 6:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice6);
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted :) Now I see where my problem is.

Comment: @Rado you are welcome, if it works please accept my answer please :)